# How do you suggest moving a question to another SE?

Tags: support, questions, migration, moderation

I understand that question can me migrated from one SE to another, and I suppose only a mod can do this. How do you suggest a migration/bringing a question to a mod's attention? Especially if it's an old question, perhaps no mod will ever notice if I only comment on the question.

Comment: 2c: Please also make sure you know the question is on-topic at the site you intend to migrate to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the recent update of the [flagging dialog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/), you should flag the post:

- "it doesn't belong here"
- "off topic"
- choose the target site from the [available migration paths](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/)

If none of them are applicable, you could still leave a short message for a mod.

Answer (score 3):

At 3000 rep you can migrate questions as part of the closing process.  Until then you can flag them for moderator attention and tell them you think it should be moved.

Answer (score 3):

A single moderator, or five users with 3k+ reputation can vote to migrate the question (you can also vote on your own questions with 250+ reputation). You can use the "flag" button (see below the tags on the left side) to get a moderator's attention if you have that privilege on the site, while the normal voting process must happen naturally.

<strike>Note that there are a limited number of migration paths between the sites, so if the question is too far off-topic, you will have to re-ask it on the appropriate site.</strike> (This answer was written before the functionalty Chris mentions existed.)

Comment: Moderators can migrate to any site via the "mod" menu, so flagging is appropriate and it's not necessary to re-ask.

Comment: @Chris: Mods can migrate to *any* site in the network? I didn't know that. What about Meta sites?

Comment: Yes, that includes to any meta as well.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a question for which non of the existing migration paths are valid then flag the question for moderator attention (as detailed in [yhw42's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72868/how-do-you-suggest-moving-a-question-to-another-se/75134#75134)) regardless of whether you have voting rights or not. This will ensure that it gets seen by somebody with the ability to move it to a better place.

For an old question - if you have a vote then use it. The question will turn up on the 10K tools pages where others will see it and vote if they agree with you. If you don't have voting rights then a comment *might* be enough, after all you saw the question so others might too. Otherwise a flag is also appropriate in this case.